# App s~project does not have enough quota | Después de intentar migrar desde GS a S3

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Les explico contexto, tengo un proyecto desde años y hace un par de meses el cliente decidió dejar morir el proyecto y dejó de pagar la facturación en Google Cloud, tiene saldo pendiente.

El proyecto fue comprado por otra empresa y decidieron rescatar algunas cosas del proyecto viejo, esencialmente los archivos guardados en Google Cloud Storage (Más de 2 millones de archivos, con un total de 1.35 TB).

Los archivos estaban disponibles hacia internet, así que empecé a investigar un poco más para migrar todo lo GS hacia S3.

Justo antes de correr el comando los archivos seguían siendo accesibles.

Configuré todo y corrí el siguiente comando (de esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39333278/6241464)):

```
gsutil -m rsync -rd gs://desde-este-bucket s3://hacia-este-bucket
```

Y después de que se listaron todos los archivos, se supone debió haber empezado a transferir todo, pero tuve estas salidas

```
INFO 1018 14:04:17.222364 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #22...
INFO 1018 14:04:18.588205 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #22...
INFO 1018 14:04:20.001906 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #22...       
INFO 1018 14:04:20.634528 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #22...       
ServiceException: 429 App s~project does not have enough quota
ServiceException: 429 App s~project does not have enough quota
ServiceException: 429 App s~project does not have enough quota
ServiceException: 429 App s~project does not have enough quota
```

Y ningún archivo se copió a mi contenedor de S3.

Quise hacer una prueba más pequeña entonces agregando una carpeta con 10 archivos y hacer otra prueba solo sobre esa carpeta pero ya no pude agregar más archivo manualmente al bucket de Google.

Y cuando quise ver alguno de los archivos me apareció esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora ninguno de los archivos del bucket es accesible ni de manera manual.

Y necesito tenerlos accesibles de nuevo para intentar migrarlos.

Investigué este error pero no encuentro algo lo suficientemente claro que me diga qué sucede.

Por el saldo pendiente y la suspensión de la cuenta de facturación será que bloquearon acceso? Les repito, lleva un par de meses sin pagar la cuenta, pero los archivos eran accesibles antes de intentar el comando.

Verificando las cuotas de Google, vi que no hay nada que se acerque un poco al límite de cuota

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier solución será de gran ayuda

Comment: Not enough quota = Se acabó el rango de uso por el que se está pagando :: incrementa el tier a uno más caro -> aumenta la quota => podrás acceder a los archivos (en teoría).

Comment: Añadí más información acerca de las cuotas, puedes verificar, por favor?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la quota del proyecto?

Answer (score 0):

Si el proyecto tiene saldo pendiente entonces esta corriendo sobre los tiers de always free.

El tier de always [free](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs) es de 100GB de egreso al mes.

Si quieres poder migrar esa data tendras o que esperar a solo sacar 100GB al mes o bien pagar para tener acceso a mayor egreso.